# html layout does not update vertically after an image is loaded which affects it's parent div's height?

Tags: html, css

[<kbd>Sample of the issue</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mmgL827n/5/)

As you can see in the [included jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmgL827n/5/), when an `img` is loaded inside a `div`, the `div`'s height changes but all it's children `absolute` or `relative` position is not updated vertically. In this specific case it causes the image to be positioned too low, instead of being properly displayed in the center of the div.

If you got into devtools in Chrome, and changed the value of `bottom` to 51% the image will pop back into the correct centered position. The issue occurs affects vertical placement.

Comment: Well, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mmgL827n/6/) might solve it for you. But it's not an answer, I'm looking into it further at the moment.

Comment: I tried updating to 51% and still not centered.. I haven't seen this type of centering, if you're interested I could suggest maybe a better way to center your img..

Comment: @webkit Works here if you update from devtools after the page is loaded. I am not aware of a better way to center a div/img in css when the size is not known in advance but I don't mind a comment about that.

Comment: I usually use transform: .toCenter { position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); } http://jsfiddle.net/mmgL827n/8/

Comment: @webkit, first, this is a great comment and very helpful (I will use it for now) but afaik it doesn't support IE8 which unfortunately most of the people who will be using this application, are using. I am well aware this does not represent the general populace. Again, very neat way to accomplish the centering.

Comment: [See this url](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).
The solution in the bottom appears to support IE8. If needed, I guess I'll use the solution in the top that is more compatible with older versions of IE but I rather not for now.

Comment: Are you trying to center align the image? for me the result looks ok - You've specified top `50%` for the container, which pushes the container below the center of the page. the image again has `position:relative` and `bottom:50%` which will again push the image. Plus it has some white space on top. Finally you end up at the bottom of the page...

Comment: @Zehelvion Yes, transform only works for IE9+...

Comment: @TJ Like you said, the image has `bottom:50%` which pushes the image up unlike `top:50%` which pushes it down. If you had text instead of an image or a div with a specified height, it would be perfectly centered using the same css. The issue **only** occurs when there is an image that needs to be loaded, plus if you use devtools (in Chrome) and change the `bottom` value to 51% and back, it pops into the correct position.

Comment: I finally managed to fix the behavior. The change was simply replacing `bottom: 50%;` with `margin-top:50%;`. It appears to have good backwards compatibility. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmgL827n/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This does not explain the strange behavior but it exposes a way to allow html & css in IE8 to correctly handle and respond to a div with changing height.

Here is the way to fix the original code (not sure about compatibility):

The css looks like this:

```
.centerMagic {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.centerMagic > img {
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    margin-top: -50%;
}
```

Html looks like this:

```
<div class="centerMagic">
    <img src="someImgUrl" />
</div>
```

There appears to be another way to center content vertically that works with images that are loaded dynamically rather well (supports IE8).

The css looks like this:

```
.block {
  text-align: center;
}

.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle
 }

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="block">    
    <div class="centered">
          <img src="someUrl">
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure why and how it works but it does the trick with IE8 so I'm good. The layout does appear to update correctly when this css is used.

Credits to this [article](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) and it's contributors.